# Bootstrap carousel: prevent next/prev or indicator buttons while animating

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am trying to make a small function to stop the next/prev buttons and indicators from sliding around while the carousel is animating.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cG8j8/)

I've tried:

```
$('.carousel').on('slid',function() {
   var carousel = $(this);
   function preventClick() {
       carousel.on('click','.carousel-indicators li, .carousel-control', function() {
            return false;
       });    
   }


   function releaseClick() {
       setTimeout(function() {
           carousel.on('click','.carousel-indicators li, .carousel-control', function() {
               return true;
           });
       }, 2000);    
   }
   preventClick(); releaseClick();
});
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? Or perhaps you have a better idea?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what your html looks like for the carousel?

Comment: Supplying an example with [bootply](http://bootply.com) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be a good start. The most anyone can do with the limited information you provided is guess. Also, what version of bootstrap?

Comment: Updated my question, added fiddle link, please check. Bootstrap 2.3.2 version.

Comment: "_...stop the next/prev buttons and indicators from sliding around while the carousel is animating..._" you want to disable the carousel buttons for a set amount of time after a transition?

Comment: Yes Carrie. Do you have any idea how I can accomplish that? I've tried e.stopPropagation and buttons didn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can achieve this with the use of the `disabled` attribute.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mffox/cG8j8/6/)

Take a look at the following code:

```
var myCarousel = $("#myCarousel");

//bind forcePause() to the slide event for our carousel
myCarousel.on('slide',{ pauseAmount: 5000}, forcePause);

/**  setTimeout and disable all carousel navigation   *
*    properties for the duration of the pause         */
function forcePause(event){
    //extract pauseAmount from our bound data
    var pauseAmount = event.data.pauseAmount

    //get all the navigation properties of myCarousel
    var carouselNavElements = myCarousel.find(
        "a[href=#myCarousel], li[data-target=#myCarousel]"
    );

    //set the disabled attribute to true for the carousel's nav elements
    carouselNavElements.prop('disabled', true);
    console.log('pause started');

    //set the timer with the pauseAmount
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('pause finished');

        //"reenable" the nav elements
        carouselNavElements.prop('disabled', false);
    }, pauseAmount);
}

//this is already built-in functionality for anchors in bootstrap, just add support for li
$('body').on('click', 'li.disabled', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Keep in mind that we bound it to the `slide` event so this will force a pause of the automatic event triggering of the carousel as well ie:

```
myCarousel.carousel({
  interval: 2000 
});
```

If that's unwanted, you can change the event to `click` and bind it to the `nav` elements but you'll have to manually manage the event.

Comment: Congratulations! You're the winner :) Now I have to adopt this to work with swipe events as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a promise by using `.promise()` and then add a [`.done()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) handler.

Better for BS slider would be "slid". Slid is fired when the event is done. Does the same thing what you want I think.

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {   alert("Slide Event"); })
```

edit 3: Working example here:
http://www.bootply.com/118355

Comment: Perhaps having a code example as you see it would be better? Meanwhile I am reading the docs on the two you've mentioned and I think it's the way to go, let me do some checking and thanks for the answer, I will mark asap.

Comment: Updated my question, added fiddle link, please check.

Comment: Your example does not help, I removed the slide class http://www.bootply.com/118353 and the alert is triggered instantly, and I don't want that, check my fiddle for better example.

Comment: @idonteven, Your example helped me. Thanks for that. It is the way I want to implement something.

Comment: yeah no problem :) glad i could help :) would be nice if you would  upvote the answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

What version of bootstrap are you using? As I assume you are talking about twitter bootstrap.

Can you make sure you upgrade to the latest version (2.3.s if you are using bootstrap 2 and 3.1.1 if you are using bootstrap 3 because neither
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel
nor
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
have a problem like you described.

Comment: Bootstrap 2.3.2. I am not using regular Bootstrap animations, I just want to stop button default actions for a short delay, say 2000ms.

Comment: please update the question with that code too, the html that you use to create the carousel.

Comment: @MihaiP This could probably have been a comment as it isn't really an answer to the question (yet).

Comment: It would have been an answer if he would have used an old version of bootstrap or jquery.

Comment: There is no need for a HTML source, you can just take default HTML examples from Bootstrap take them to jsfiddle and try your best to give it a 2000ms delay for the buttons after the slid event.

Comment: I could do that yes, but it is in your interest to give us all the details for us to help solve your problem. When I ask a question, I create the js fiddle to help people help me.. but that is just me. Good luck anyway.

Comment: @Mihai P. I updated my question and added a fiddle, please check.